# Attach Excel cell styles to theme file

Tags: microsoft-excel, themes, styles

If I create a new workbook not from a template and then go Page Layout > Themes > select the custom theme I want, it updates the colours and font but does not update the 'Styles' gallery on the Home tab.

I have access to a template that has in-house styles as well, but wondering if there's a way to embed the custom cell styles in the theme so that choosing a theme also updates the cell styles, and can then start from any blank workbook rather than needing the template.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried opening the template, then going to Themes, and click "save current theme"? Open a blank workbook, recall the custom these and check if the cell style gets saved as well. I suspect, since you can save both the style and the theme separately, that they will not save together.  Best you can do is edit the default Excel blank template and add the cell styles you require (e.g. see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-how-excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19)

Comment: Used VBA in the end